# Total number of integers between $100$ and $1000$ such that $7$ appears as at least one of its digits.

Tags: number-theory

How many number between $100$ to $1000$ such that atleast one of its digit is $7$?

My attempt:  Any number between $100$ and $1000$ is three digit number. Required number =   total number - ( $7$ appears almost one of the digits ) . So by permutation, first place ( unit place ) can be filled by $9$ ways ( from $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9$ ) and 2nd place ( tens place ) can be filled by $9$ ways ( from $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9$ ) and 3rd place ( hundredth place ) can be filled by $8$ ways ($1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9$). So required answer $= 899-648 = 251$ . My question is that can this type of problem handle by number theory? Find the answer by using number theory.

Comment: Number theory, in its most elementary form, doesn't care about bases. "There is a 7 in this number" is a thing particular to our base-ten number system (try to describe that property using addition, subtraction, multiplication and divisibility, and you will see that it becomes rather convoluted). From this follows that it will be difficult to approach a solution.

Comment: Thank you sir for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Using inclusion-exclusion:
$$**7 \Rightarrow 90\\
*7*\Rightarrow 90\\
7** \Rightarrow 100\\
*77 \Rightarrow 9\\
7*7\Rightarrow 10\\
77*\Rightarrow 10\\
777\Rightarrow 1\\
90+90+100-9-10-10+1=252.$$

Answer (score 1):

You are missing one. Since you allow zeros in the first and second place, $100$ is included. Therefore, the correct calculation is $900-648=252$.

You can also check by counting in a different way.

$100$ numbers have a $7$ in the third place.

Excluding those, $10\times 8$ numbers have a $7$ in the second place.

Excluding all those, $9\times 8$ numbers have a $7$ in the first place.

$100+80+72=252$.